# A question about paypal IPN

Tags: paypal

i download sample code from 
https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/nvp_DoDirectPayment_php.txt

run and get

```
TIMESTAMP=2010%2d05%2d11T04%3a42%3a06Z&CORRELATIONID=ac15852d1e958&ACK=Failure&VERSION=51%2e0&BUILD=1268624&L_ERRORCODE0=10002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Security%20error&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Security%20header%20is%20not%20valid&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error' (length=233)
```

what is problem ?
api username ? api pass ? signature or anything else ?

this infor i fill in source code:

```
// Set request-specific fields.
$paymentType = urlencode('Authorization');              // or 'Sale'
$firstName = urlencode('Nguyen');
$lastName = urlencode('Quang Trung');
$creditCardType = urlencode('Visa');
$creditCardNumber = urlencode(' 

4111111111111111');
$expDateMonth = '04';
// Month must be padded with leading zero
$padDateMonth = urlencode(str_pad($expDateMonth, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));

$expDateYear = urlencode('2015');
$cvv2Number = urlencode('5360 ');
$address1 = urlencode('ha noi');
$address2 = urlencode('hcm');
$city = urlencode('ha noi');
$state = urlencode('ha noi state');
$zip = urlencode('84');
$country = urlencode('viet nam');               // US or other valid country code
$amount = urlencode('900');
$currencyID = urlencode('USD');                         // or other currency ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')
```

Comment: Uh... What? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: when i get TIMESTAMP=2010%2d05%2d11T04%3a42%3a06Z&CORRELATIONID=ac15852d1e958&ACK=Failure&VERSION=51%2e0&BUILD=1268624&L_ERRORCODE0=10002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Security%20error&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Security%20header%20is%20not%20valid&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error' (length=233)

 ACK=Failure and view code , i think payment failure and don't know why it stop .where step ? login pay pal or transaction ?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the error codes [here](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_errorcodes). Also the reponse from Paypal clearly says there is a `Security Header is not valid`.

```
LONGMESSAGE0=Security%20header%20is%20not%20valid
```

Make sure you enter the correct API Password, Username etc

Comment: thank to you , i will try it .But in sandbox , how to fill all infor of credit card , haven't a credit card :D

Comment: I think you can try 4111111111111111 which is a valid credit card format.

Answer (score 0):

As previous answers mentioned, you need a valid card number. It is [very easy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) to make up your own, I used MS Excel before. But you can just use [this site](http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/) for quick and easy card numbers.

Also I recommend for you to create a [sandbox account](https://developer.paypal.com/) (if you haven't yet) as it will help you debug most of your issues.

P.S. Just noticed it's 2010 question :(